# Laravel validate json data

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

in this code i'm try to validate json data but validater return false

```
        $username = $data['username'];
        $password = $data['password'];

        $input = Input::json();
        $rules = array(
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        );
        $input_array = (array)$input;
        $validation = Validator::make($input_array, $rules);
        if ($validation->fails()) {
            var_dump( $input_array );
        }else {
                $result = array('code'=>'3');
            }
```

var_dump result is :

```
array(1) {  ["parameters"]=>  array(3) {    ["password"]=>    string(9) "world"    ["username"]=>    string(1) "hello"    ["function"]=>    string(8) "register"  }}""
```

username and password is not null and `$validation` must be return true. but return false

Answer (score 2):

Your var_dump shows the data you're trying to validate is inside a 'parameters' array.  You either need to change your rules to include the parameters, or you need to pass the parameters array to the validate method.

Option 1 - change your rules:

```
$rules = array(
    'parameters.username' => 'required',
    'parameters.password' => 'required',
);
$input_array = (array)$input;
$validation = Validator::make($input_array, $rules);
```

Option 2 - validate the data in the parameters array:

```
$rules = array(
    'username' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required',
);
$input_array = (array)$input;
$validation = Validator::make($input_array['parameters'], $rules);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that has worked for me.

```
$InputData = array('username' =>Input::json('username'),
                    'password'=>Input::json('password'));

$validation = Validator::make( $InputData,array('username'=>'required|email','password'=>'required'));
```

Hope you find it usefull.